# MongoDB - elemMatch with range of numbers not working as expected?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents which looks like this:

```
_id1:
Price:[1,100000]

_id2:
Price:[1,98500]

_id3:
Price:[1,3005]

..etc
```

Following this documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

I tried reproduce the find for elements which are in a certain price range but unfortunately it doesn't work for me, I get back all of my elements even though they are not matching the criteria. What am I doing wrong?

My query:

```
{ Price:{ $elemMatch: { $gte: 1, $lt: 85 } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) has already mentioned,

> *The `$elemMatch` operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.*

Lets debug your document and input why its result all documents,

> **true** = (1 >= 1 **&&** 1 < 85) 
> or 
> **false** = (100000/98500/3005 >= 1 **&&** 100000/98500/3005 < 85)

There is a value `1` which is true in every document so `$elemMatch` will result document if one of the element in array has true condition.

---

You can use alternate option to fulfil your requirement,

- `$expr` to match expression conditions
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `Price` array and match both condition,
- `$eq` to check filtered `Price` array and actual `Price` array both should be same

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Price",
          cond: {
            $and: [{ $gte: ["$$this", 1] }, { $lt: ["$$this", 85] }]
          }
        }
      },
      "$Price"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vYjJ3T_bIiw)